# Phantom Joomla! Record

Tags: mysql, joomla

I am having a very strange issue with Joomla.  When I link to or directly pull up record # 571, what gets displayed is NOT what is in the database.  In fact what is being displayed is not in the database at all.  I have searched on all fields for any likeness to the contents of this article (which was created in the past) but I can not find any reference to it. I have tried doing this using the mysql CLI and the Joomla article manager, there is no evidence of this record to be found anywhere.

Has anybody experienced anything like this before? What in the world could cause this, I mean if the data isn't in the database and there is a valid record with this ID, how in the world does this get displayed!?

-- Nicholas

Comment: clean your cache and check again

Comment: Browser cache? Cleared, unfortunately not the problem.

Comment: It is starting to look like a glitch in the MySQL replication process we have running, i'll be back with a report after I confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with our MySQL replication process, for a still to be determined reason the record was not being sync'd over so deleting the record (even though it was correct in the database), recreating it and updating the links solved the problem.

-- Nicholas

Answer (score 0):

could it be that your records are being loaded from another db? is this a fresh install on a new server?

Check your configuration.php file arround line 30 - 35 for

```
var $dbtype = 'mysql';
var $host = 'localhost';
var $user = 'root';
var $db = 'joomla';
```

You never know...!

Comment: Sadly no, this install is pointing to the correct database. I can pull up any ID in the database, visit the url with that ID and (of course) the record/content matches... that is true of ALL records except for this phantom 571.